# ¿Cómo puedo insertar filas en una tabla hecha con 'Treeview' mientras recorro un bucle 'for', en tiempo real y no una vez ejecutado el bucle?

Tags: python, tablas

El problema de mi consulta es que al ejecutar un bucle 'for' y pasar los valores a la tabla hecha con 'Treeview', estos valores, pasan al final de la ejecución del bucle todos de golpe y no de uno en uno, dejando la aplicacion en espera como si no estuviera haciendo nada.

¿Cómo se podrían ir pasando en tiempo real, mientras el bucle 'for' se esta ejecutando?

Añado código de prueba, el 'input' es para controlar si van pasando de uno en uno ya que sino pasan muy rápido:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

vent = root

vent.geometry("1280x960+300+30")
vent.resizable(False, False)


valores = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

def insertar(valor1, valor2):
    tabla.insert("", END, text="", values=(valor1, valor2))

def buscar():
    for i in valores:
        print(i)

        insertar(valor1=i, valor2=i+1)
        input()

# Interfaz grafica

boton_buscar = Button(vent, text="BUSCAR ", width=25, height=2, fg="red", command=buscar)
boton_buscar.place(x=40, y=900)

boton_salir = Button(vent, text="SALIR", width=15, height=1, command=quit)
boton_salir.place(x=1130, y=900)


#Frame para la tabla
frame_tabla = Frame(vent)
frame_tabla.pack(pady=190)
#frame_tabla.place(x=1225, y=190)

# Scrollbar para la tabla
scrolltabla = Scrollbar(frame_tabla)
scrolltabla.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)


# Tabla principal
columnas = ("valor1", "valor2")
tabla = ttk.Treeview(frame_tabla, height=15, show="headings", columns=columnas, yscrollcommand=scrolltabla.set, selectmode="browse")
tabla.column("valor1", width=220, anchor='center')
tabla.heading("valor1", text="valor1")
tabla.column("valor2", width=683, anchor='w')
tabla.heading("valor2", text="valor2")
tabla.pack(pady=0)
#tabla.place(x=40, y=190)
scrolltabla.config(command=tabla.yview)  


vent.mainloop()
```

Muchas gracias ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update por cada registro y sus desventajas

Se puede enviar a actualizar la ventana usando el método universal `update`. Esto hará que se redibuje la ventana (incluyendo el treeview) y se procesen los eventos (entre ellos, presionar teclas y hacer clic, ten en cuenta esto para tu aplicación final, pues el usuario podría interactuar con la ventana mientras el treeview carga).

Pero hacer un update por cada registro en tiempo real, es algo costoso en cuanto a tiempo. Supongo que esto se debe a que el update no retorna hasta que Tcl (la base sobre la que está construida Tkinter) redibuja la ventana. De hecho, la demora es muy significativa:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree.pack()

def method():
    for i in range(1000):
        tree.insert("", "end", text=i)

def method2():
    for i in range(1000):
        tree.insert("", "end", text=i)
        tree.update()

from timeit import timeit

print("sin update", timeit(method, number=1), "s")
print("con update", timeit(method2, number=1), "s")

root.mainloop()
```

Que produce:

```
sin update 0.008006982000000051 s
con update 3.124947649 s
```

Hablamos de que se tarda aproximadamente 500 veces más tiempo, y esto solo tratando de ingresar 1000 registros.

#### Mi intento de usar hilos

Intenté usar hilos, es decir, hacer el proceso de redibujar la ventana en un hilo separado, pero resultó en lo mismo. De todas formas, lo pensé un poco y no creo que sea seguro que se actualize la ventana mientras se ingresan registros en el treeview. Estaría intentando obligar a tcl a hacer dos cosas a la vez, y no creo que esté pensado para eso.

#### Actualización por tiempo

Entonces, se me ocurre usar un sistema de actualizar la ventana cada cierto tiempo. No se logra el efecto de que se vayan ingresando de a uno, pero al menos no dejas al usuario con la interfaz tan trabada.

El siguiente código, si se presiona 3, ingresa registros y actualiza la ventana cada 100 milisegundos:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree.pack()

def method():
    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
    
    for i in range(1_000_000):
        tree.insert("", "end", text=i)
        
def forma_con_timer():
    import time

    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())

    starttime = time.time()
    tree.update()
    
    for i in range(1_000_000):
        tree.insert("", "end", text=i, iid=i)

        endtime = time.time()

        if(endtime - starttime >= 0.1):
            tree.see(i)
            tree.update()

            # Si tree.winfo_exists() da un error TclError, entonces la aplicación fue destruida.
            # Si tree.winfo_exists() devuelve False, entonces dejó de existir el treeview.
            try:
                if(not tree.winfo_exists()):
                    return
            except tk.TclError:
                return
            
            starttime = endtime

from timeit import timeit

root.bind("1", lambda e:print("sin update", timeit(method, number=1)))
root.bind("3", lambda e:print("usando timers", timeit(forma_con_timer, number=1)))
```

Presionar 1 y 3, resultará en:

```
sin update 7.882355141
usando timers 9.867686987
```

Es un par de segundos mas lenta, pero estamos trabajando con un millon de registros, por lo que podemos ver que no es tan grave como antes la espera.
Cuanto menos actualices el treeview, más rapido funcionará el bucle.

Comment: Muchas gracias @dante-s por tus aportaciones, concretamente la ultima la probaré y trataré de entender como funciona para adaptarla a mi aplicación, ya que no estoy tan experimentado todavía, de todas formas, me sirve como posible solución, a falta de pan...ya sabes.
Lo que me sorprende, es que no haya una forma de hacer lo que inicialmente exponía en mi consulta. ¿Quizá sea mejor emplear otro tipo de tablas en vez de treeview? ¿Se te/os ocurre alguna forma de lograrlo quizá con otro modulo?
Ahora al menos ya se que no había una solución sencilla, muchas gracias. ;)

Comment: De nada! No existe otro widget para hacer tablas en Tkinter (aunque me pareció que si en tcl, no se casi nada de tcl). Y incluso si hubiera, dudo que dieran una forma. Si supiera de otro modulo, te lo hubiera avisado. La problematica real, es (probablemente) que el proceso de dibujado consume mucho tiempo, razón por la que intenté separarlo en hilos, para hacerlo asincronicamente.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente como comentaba @dante-s he conseguido presentar los resultados en la tabla treeview en tiempo real mientras se recorre el bucle for.
Ha sido tan simple como añadir un 'update' a la ventana principal (vent.update()).

Quedando en mi caso, el código de esta forma (ver función buscar):

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

vent = root

vent.geometry("1280x960+300+30")
vent.resizable(False, False)


def insertar(valor1, valor2):
    tabla.insert("", END, text="", values=(valor1, valor2))

def buscar():
    for i in range(100000):
        print(i)

        insertar(valor1=i, valor2=i+1)
        vent.update()


# Interfaz grafica

boton_buscar = Button(vent, text="BUSCAR ", width=25, height=2, fg="red", command=buscar)
boton_buscar.place(x=40, y=900)

boton_salir = Button(vent, text="SALIR", width=15, height=1, command=quit)
boton_salir.place(x=1130, y=900)


#Frame para la tabla
frame_tabla = Frame(vent)
frame_tabla.pack(pady=190)
#frame_tabla.place(x=1225, y=190)

# Scrollbar para la tabla
scrolltabla = Scrollbar(frame_tabla)
scrolltabla.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)


# Tabla principal
columnas = ("valor1", "valor2")
tabla = ttk.Treeview(frame_tabla, height=15, show="headings", columns=columnas, yscrollcommand=scrolltabla.set, selectmode="browse")
tabla.column("valor1", width=220, anchor='center')
tabla.heading("valor1", text="valor1")
tabla.column("valor2", width=683, anchor='w')
tabla.heading("valor2", text="valor2")
tabla.pack(pady=0)
#tabla.place(x=40, y=190)
scrolltabla.config(command=tabla.yview)


vent.mainloop()
```

Ahora ya se muestra la salida del 'for' en tiempo real en 'Treeview', a medida que se va recorriendo.
De momento no he observado otros problemas, desconozco los posibles 'efectos secundarios' en caso de tener que recorrer o realizar operaciones muy complejas en el bucle 'for' como comentaba Dante, pero para mi ha sido la solución que estaba buscando, por si a otros les pudiera ser de utilidad.

Gracias a todos y a ti @dante-s, una vez más, por vuestra ayuda. ;)

Comment: De nada, un placer ayudar! Solo una cosa que decir, ten en cuenta que tanto print como update son funciones que tardan mucho en terminar de ejecutarse, lo que significa el ingreso de datos en el treeview es mucho mas lento que sin esas cosas. Te recomiendo que uses esta tecnica si la cantidad de datos es poca o la frecuencia con la que se insertan datos es de, por ejemplo, un segundo por dato. Para ver otros efectos secundarios del update, [lee mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/579144/158880)